# How to optimize the following delete SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

I have a following `delete` query in oracle. There will be about 1000 records to be deleted from the database at a time.

I have used "in" the query. Is there any better way to write this query?

```
DELETE FROM BI_EMPLOYEE_ACTIVITY      
WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID in (    
    SELECT    
      EMP_ID   
    FROM   
      BI_EMPLOYEE   
    WHERE   
      PRODUCT_ID = IN_PRODUCT_ID  
  );
```

Comment: Putting index on EMP_ID may help, I dont believe if any other optimization is possible, query is quite simple and straight forward

Comment: Why do you need to optimize? are you facing performance issues? in 1000 records you shouldnt be facing any problems actually. besides the Query looks just fine.

Comment: @O.D OP is deleting 1000 records but we do not know from how many records he is selecting those hundred. If there 10 Mil+ records to search, there may be performance issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really possible to answer this question as we're missing a description of the data distribution: How many rows are in each table? What's the relationship between the tables? How many rows are affected by the delete?

I'll be assuming that both tables are large (since this is an optimization question) and that `BI_EMPLOYEE` and `BI_EMPLOYEE_ACTIVITY` have a parent-child 1..N relationship.

If there are few rows affected by the delete, this means that not many employees have the same `PRODUCT_ID` and each employee has few activities. In this case it would make sense to index both `BI_EMPLOYEE (product_id)` and `BI_EMPLOYEE_ACTIVITY (employee_id)`.

This is probably not the case though, the delete probably affects lots of rows. In that case the indexes could be a hindrance. If the delete affects lots of rows, the fastest access path probably is `FULL TABLE SCAN + HASH JOIN`.

We need some metrics here: how many rows are deleted? How long does it take? This is because large DML will always take time, especially `DELETE` since they produce the largest amount of undo.

There are alternatives to a large `DELETE`, as explained in ["Deleting many rows from a big table"](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2345591157689) from asktom:

1. recreate the table without the deleted rows
2. partition the data, do a parallel delete
3. partition the data so that the delete is done by dropping a partition

Comment: Hi Tables will not be that large. BI_EMPLOYEE might have at most around 20,000. It might increase to a large extent in future though. An employee can have multiple activities, so yes, this table will be huge.

Comment: What about the other questions? How many rows are affected by the update? How long does it take? What's your goal performance-wise?

Answer (score 0):

Putting index on EMP_ID may help, I dont believe if any other optimization is possible, query is quite simple and straight forward

Answer (score 0):

Create an index on PRODUCT_ID column. This would speed up the search. If the column is of varchar type, make use to function index if you are converting values to uppercase or lowercase

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try [EXIST](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/05/18/60210.aspx) instead of IN:

```
DELETE FROM BI_EMPLOYEE_ACTIVITY      
WHERE EXISTS (    
    SELECT    
      EMP_ID   
    FROM   
      BI_EMPLOYEE   
    WHERE   
      PRODUCT_ID = IN_PRODUCT_ID 
    AND
      EMP_ID =  EMPLOYEE_ID
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an index on `BI_EMPLOYEE` table for `PRODUCT_ID, EMP_ID` columns in this order (product_id on the first place).

And create an index on the `BI_EMPLOYEE_ACTIVITY` table for the column `EMPLOYEE_ID`

Answer (score 0):

I'll just add that other than creating an index for the query, you need to take a look at the locking issue when your table grows really big, try to lock the table in exclusive mode (if possible) as this will only take a lock from the db, and if it's not possible try to commit the delete over each 2500 records so if you're stuck with row locking you don't endup starving the database of locks.